# How to give new life into a five years old, simple but reliable PHP form?

Tags: php, variables, forms, post, get

I have a script in php 5.2. I want to use a simple form. I found something a programmer made for me about 5 years ago. When I use it, PHP outputs an error now unless I set `register_long_arrays = On`, then it works fine.

On the PHP website, however, it says:

> **Warning** *This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature
>   is highly discouraged. It's recommended to turn them off, for performance reasons.
>   Instead, use the superglobal arrays, like `$_GET`.*

Should I listen to PHP's warning, or just enable the option and keep using my old form happily? If the former, then how/where do I change this simple form, so it does not rely on the deprecated setting? Your answer is much appreciated.

**form.htm**

```
<html><body>
<form method="POST" action="form_sent.php"> 
  ...   
</form>
</body></html>
```

**form_sent.php**

```
<html><body>
<?php
$email = $HTTP_POST_VARS[email];
$mailto = "info@website.com";
$mailsubj = "A Form was Sent from Website!";
$mailhead = "From: $email\n";
reset ($HTTP_POST_VARS);
$mailbody = "Values submitted from web site form:\n";
while (list($key, $val) = each ($HTTP_POST_VARS)){$mailbody .= "$key : $val\n";}
if (!eregi("\n",$HTTP_POST_VARS[email])) {
   mail($mailto, $mailsubj, $mailbody, $mailhead); }
?>

<b>Form Sent. Thank you.</b>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simple.  Change where you have `$HTTP_POST_VARS` and use `$_POST` in its place.

So, you will end up with:

```
<html><body>
<?php
$email = $_POST[email];
$mailto = "info@website.com";
$mailsubj = "A Form was Sent from Website!";
$mailhead = "From: $email\n";
$mailbody = "Values submitted from web site form:\n";
while (list($key, $val) = each ($_POST)){$mailbody .= "$key : $val\n";}
if (!eregi("\n",$_POST[email])) {
   mail($mailto, $mailsubj, $mailbody, $mailhead); }
?>

<b>Form Sent. Thank you.</b>
</body></html>
```

And, yes you should definitely listen to the PHP documentation and make these changes.  I'm actually surprised those old superglobals haven't been removed already.

Also, no need for the `reset()` part.  It was likely leftover from an old version of this form using the internal array pointer, but you're not using the array pointer.  You are using it as an associative array.

Comment: Thanks Brad for your quick answer. Interesting so i can delete that reset line. Now testing.... WORKS GREAT :O)

Comment: +1 for being first, -1 for copying me about taking `reset()` out. :)

Comment: Dont you love it when five years old php bits are recycled, new fresh love and energy from other happy people like yourselves goes into it again, and then ... then its lifespan instantly lengthened for another five years... it will breathe happy life again! Crazy, yet true! :)

Comment: @JMC, I was in the middle of editing my post and then read yours after I had posted my edit.  Sorry if I made you feel like I copied your suggestion... plagiarism was definitely not my intention.  +1 for you.

Answer (score 4):

It's the `$HTTP_POST_VARS` that's giving you trouble. Take it out and replace it with `$_POST`. Also, I *think* you should take out `reset ($HTTP_POST_VARS);`, that's not helping you that I can see.

```
<html><body>
<?php
$email = $_POST[email];
$mailto = "info@website.com";
$mailsubj = "A Form was Sent from Website!";
$mailhead = "From: $email\n";

$mailbody = "Values submitted from web site form:\n";
while (list($key, $val) = each ($_POST)){$mailbody .= "$key : $val\n";}
if (!eregi("\n",$_POST[email])) {
   mail($mailto, $mailsubj, $mailbody, $mailhead); }
?>

<b>Form Sent. Thank you.</b>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Thanks JMC for your quick and full answer!!

Comment: ...and @Sam, on the note of recycling the old form, you may want to look at adding some kind of spam limiting field, like a captcha.

Comment: Thanks JMC, indeed perhaps a welcome addon. To be very frank, I always feel like a robot, when I have to sueeze my eyes and fill in the strange letters... On one hand I think its not needed, on the other hand, comon its 2011, shouldnt the forms have better A.I. to find out wether a spam-server is fishing the sites, or a real human with real mouse movements, real reading delays etc is filling in the form?  Just the fact that a person takes a few seconds to fill in the various fields, as opposed to robots who do things instantly/according to non-random patterns, can be proof of human behayour!

Comment: Wether and how to completely update the captcha so that thscript can SMELL if you are human or robot:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683117/annoying-captcha-how-to-programm-a-form-that-can-smell-difference-between-huma?tab=newest#tab-top